# How to print total sum before fetching value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print the total sum before while loop that fetch rows from mysql database

I know that i should fetch the rows than print the variable put my question is there any methode to print the variable before the while loop

I try to do that

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($projectQuery);
```

and than print `$row['sum'];`

than

```
while($row){ }
```

But this idea didn't work my code don't work i don't have any result

```
$projectQuery=mysqli_query($conn,"
          select 
          project.*,
          location.db_lid,
          location.db_location as loc,
          concat(tr.db_fname,' ',tr.db_lname) as trans,
          tr.db_uid,
          concat(user.db_fname,' ',user.db_lname) as name,
          user.db_uid,
          client.db_clientid,
          client.db_name as clientname,
          department.db_did,
          department.db_department as dep,
          supplier.db_id,
          supplier.db_CompanyName,
          sum(activities.db_newtotal) as total
          from tbl_project as project
          left join tbl_location as location
          on
          project.db_location=location.db_lid
          left join tbl_user as tr
          on 
          project.db_transferredto=tr.db_uid
          left join tbl_user as user
          on
          project.db_user=user.db_uid
          left join tbl_client as client
          on
          project.db_client=client.db_clientid
          left join tbl_department as department
          on 
          project.db_department=department.db_did
          left join tbl_supplier as supplier
          on
          project.db_transsub=supplier.db_id
          left join tbl_activities as activities
          on
          project.db_projectid=activities.db_projectname
          {$q}
          group by project.db_projectid order by project.db_projectid desc
          ")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
          $count=mysqli_num_rows($projectQuery);

          if($count!=0){
        echo"<h2>You Have $count project </h2>";?>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class='ol-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf table-bordered' id="alternatecolor">
        <thead class='cf'>
            <tr>
            <th rowspan='2'>#</th>
            <th rowspan='2'>Date</th>
            <th rowspan='2'>Project</th>
            <th rowspan='2'>Location</th>
            <th rowspan='2'>Cleint</th>
            <th rowspan='2'>Project Manager</th>
            <th rowspan='2'>Staff</th>
            <th rowspan='2'>Subcontractor</th>
            <th rowspan='2'>Company Name</th>
            <th rowspan='2'>Department</th>
            <th colspan='3'>Planing</th>
            <th rowspan='2'>%</th>
            <th rowspan='2'>Civil %</th> 
            <th rowspan='2'>Electrical %</th> 
            <th rowspan='2'>Mechanical %</th> 
            <th rowspan='2'>Total Cost</th> 
            <th rowspan='2'>Note</th> 
            <th rowspan='2'>Checklist</th> 
            <th rowspan='2'>Add</th> 
            <th rowspan='2'>Print</th> 
            <th rowspan='2'>Status</th>
            <th rowspan='2'></th>
            <th rowspan='2'>Edit</th>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th> Start Date</th>
                <th> Due Date</th>
                <th >Duration</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
              $totalSum=0;
              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($projectQuery)){
                  $projectid=$row['db_projectid'];
                  $projectName=$row['db_projectname'];
                  $location=$row['loc'];
                  $transferred=$row['trans'];
                  $psd=$row['db_psd'];
                  $pdd=$row['db_pdd'];
                  $duration=$row['db_duration'];
                  $asd=$row['db_past'];
                  $add=$row['db_padd'];
                  $aduration=$row['db_aduration'];
                  $percent=$row['db_percent'];
                  $note=$row['db_pnote'];
                  $staff=$row['name'];
                  $client=$row['clientname'];
                  $cPercent=$row['db_cpercentage'];
                  $ePercent=$row['db_epercentage'];
                  $mPercent=$row['db_mpercentage'];
                  $status=$row['db_status'];
                  $supp=$row['db_CompanyName'];
                  $companyName=$row['db_companyname'];
                  $department=$row['dep'];
                  $clientid=$row['db_clientid'];
                  $date=$row['db_date'];
                  $totaCost=$row['total'];
                  $totalSum+=$row['total'];

            ?>
```

in this part off my code i want to print the totalSum

```
echo"<h2>You Have $count project </h2>";
```

The code will be like this

You have $count project Total sum $totalSum

Comment: You want a `sum` of the number of rows or what?

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you want to do, but I think you're confusing looping and retrieving data with _printing_ data. You need to retrieve data from the database before you can use it, but you _don't_ need to print it at that time. Store your data in a variable and print it out later.

Comment: @chris85 no i want to print the sum before the while loop if you look to my code i have a variable name totalSum i want to print this variable in the <h2></h2> like i put above and this sentence in before the while loop

Comment: That won't be available until you iterate over the whole result object.

Comment: @chris85 that mean if i want to do it i need to create a new query and fetch the sum than print the value

Comment: @Developer, no, you don't need to create a new query. As I said in my previous comment, fetching data and printing data are different things. You can fetch it once and print it 100 times, in any order you want. But your loop doesn't seem to _do_ anything other than assign a bunch of variables. I'm guessing it's incomplete?

Comment: Is there any reason you need to output before the loop? I'm guessing you are outputting in this loop? If that is the case I wouldn't do that. Use the loop to build your data, then do the outputting later in your script.

Comment: @Chris if you look at my code i have create a table to print my variable on it but i didn't put it above in the while loop i have echo td like that <td><?php echo $projectid;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>     
                <td><?php echo $projectName;?></td> to have a table

Comment: @chris85 can you please give me an example on what you mean

Comment: Do the query and data storage before you begin outputting. Store results in an array rather than a one time variable. Then iterate over that array later in your code as you need it.

Comment: @chris85 can you please an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code,

```
$totalSum=0;
$projects = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($projectQuery)){
  $totalSum+=$row['total'];
  $projects[] = $row;
}

echo"<h2>You Have $totalSum project </h2>";

foreach($projects AS $project) {
  //you can loop through your records here
}
```

this exactly follows the approach explained by @Chris

Also, one more suggestion. You don't need to assign each value into a variable before using it. Instead you can directly use the values like $row['db_projectname']